# Is there an English word or acronym for someone who goes out of their way to tell other people how stupid/fake their beliefs/interests are?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example: an atheist who goes out of his way to find Christian forums and posts comments about it being rubbish and people who believe in it stupid. Basically people who think they are so much more enlightened and intelligent than everyone else and make sure everyone with different interests knows how ignorant they are and how smart he is. Another acronym like 'SJW' perhaps?

Comment: Not a match, but FWIW, the term "strident" is often hurdled  around in this context. So Dawkins has been accused of being a "strident atheist" on exactly these grounds.

Comment: Do you want something purely ad-homonym like SJW, or perhaps something more grounded in the content of the argument?

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence so we can see how you want to use the word.

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 2):

For a more coloquial term, you could say a “troll,” although it’s used more often online. It’s a little bit insulting. 
“Don’t pay attention to the internet trolls; they’re just bullies.”

Comment: Further to Jonah's suggestion, the [Wikipedia entry for Internet Troll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll) has a great explanation of the Chinese term for Internet troll " literally: "white eye"), which can be straightforwardly explained as "eyes without pupils", in the sense that whilst the pupil of the eye is used for vision, the white section of the eye cannot see, and trolling involves blindly talking nonsense over the Internet, having total disregard to sensitivities or being oblivious to the situation at hand, akin to having eyes without pupils."

Answer (score 0):

[bigot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigot)

> bigot

noun

big·​ot | ˈbi-gət

> : a person who is obstinately or intolerantly devoted to his or her
>   own opinions and prejudices ...

Comment: I think I'll watch a few *'All in the Family'* reruns.

Comment: @Jeeped Hadn't heard of that, looked it up, funny.

Comment: No: please be clear: going out of your way to tell other people how stupid/fake their beliefs/interests are is one thing… being right or wrong about that is rather different…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I understand what you're getting at. The tone of the OP's post indicates a strong emotional bias, so that is what I answered, in good faith - irrespective of politics, ideology, maturity, mental health or any other of the potential issues that could surface..

Comment: Really, Duckisaduckisaduck? Does "strong emotional bias" mean "stupid/fake" or what?

Who goes out of his way to tell others how stupid/fake their beliefs/interests are might well be a bigot but by no means necessarily…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I get your distinction, but I'm not familiar with the actual word/acronym that fits the bill and I've exhausted google. Of course expressing the meaning in a phrase or paragraph would be relativley easy.  Care to suggest your own answer?